# How to intercept Angularjs resource's action after resources are instantiated

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some `resources` with `actions`.
I need to intercept the actions' response *after* resources are instantiated.
i wish to attach to the `response-resource` (or `response-resource-array`) some meta data taken from the http-response-header..
I tried
- action's `tranformRespose` function but it's too early .. that's for the raw response string manipulation
- action's `interceptors`object but that's too early too, on response data i have the parsed resp string as a simple js-hash/js-array, and if i attach an object for meta-data it is not propagated to the returning resource-instance..
the last one is quite obvious, because the returning `resource-instance`/`resource-instance-array` from resource's action is immediatly empty-returned and then lazyly populated..
Any idea to achieve what i need in some way, avoiding big hacks?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why i didn't see the very simple solution before..
the action's `interceptors.response` function's argument has both the `data` property wich is the simple `jshash`/`array` *and* the `resource` property wich is the action's method returned object with all resources already instantiated !
That's all!